# Prevent scrolling webpage before clicking specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, elementor

Currently I'm using WordPress and Elementor for my website builder. I want to prevent scrolling on my page before clicking specific button. The script that I use is working to prevent the scrolling but after I click the button it still prevent my webpage to scroll. Im using this code:

```
<script>
 disableScrolling()
 document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
 document.body.style.heigth="100vh"


document.getElementById("open-invitation").onclick = function() {
   myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
   playAudio()
   document.body.style.overflowY = "unset";
   enableScrolling()   
}  

function disableScrolling(){ 
   var x=window.scrollX;
   var y=window.scrollY;
   window.onscroll=function(){
      window.scrollTo(x, y);
};
 
} 
function enableScrolling(){ 
     window.onscroll=function(){};
}
  
</script>
```

This code work well for prevent scrolling but when I click the button with the Id "open-invitation" that I set the onclick function it still prevent scrolling and stuck my page on the first column

I have try to separate the onclick function and put it beside the button that assign to it and still didn't work I'm using elementor and also I put every id and CSS id with "open-invitation" and also it wont help

Comment: Are you sure that there is an element `#open-invitation` and that `playAudio` is a function? Those were the two things I had to fix before I could get this example working.

Comment: I edited the code so it's legible. You can't use  `enableScrolling()` to make it scroll. there's nothing in that function. You need to reset the CSS.

Comment: Thanks I have figure out the error it is because the playaudio function is undefined so it making the function error

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>

<title>How to disable scrolling using JavaScript?</title>

<style>

.scrollable-place {

height: 3000px;

}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1 style="color:blue">
        Welcome To Our Website
</h1>

<p>Click the buttons below to enable or disable scrolling.</p>

<p class="scrollable-place">
<button>Disable Scrolling</button>
<button>Enable Scrolling</button>
</p>

</body>

<script>
functiondisable() {
// To get the scroll position of current webpage
TopScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
LeftScroll = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,

// if scroll happens, set it to the previous value
window.onscroll = function() {
window.scrollTo(LeftScroll, TopScroll);
        };
}

functionenable() {
window.onscroll = function() {};
}
</script>

</html>
```